# Is it possible to edit Options ==> Default Value for Field in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I have created a new field "Reporter Name" with Definition Type as "Identity". I would like to change Options => Default Value from "Set the Default value to the user updating the work item" to "the user who created the work item".

I want this field set to the user who created it and not change if someone else updates the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have this option, but there is a workaround:

Choose the "Set the Default value to the user updating the work item".

Create a new Rule:

**Conditions:** When "No change was made to the value of ..." "Reporter"

**Actions:** "Make read-only ..." "Reporter"

[image]

Now, when a user create the work item the field value will be this user, when he save the work item the field became read-only and can't be changed.

When I create a work item:

[image]

After I save:

[image]